# How to change latex default textblock border color in latex

Tags: latex, textblock

I am trying hard to set textblock border color to white or no color, but failed.
Asking help from experts.

```
\begin{textblock}{3.84}(1.40,15.28)    % tweak here: {box width}(leftposition, rightposition)
     \noindent
     \textblockcolour{white}
     \footnotesize
     978-1-7281-5242-4/19 ©2019 IEEE
\end{textblock}
```

}

Comment: Can you make a minimal, but compilable example?

Comment: I just want to change the border color of the textblock

Comment: To tell you how to change the boarder colour, it would be helpful to have a small, but compilable test document that includes all the required packages.

Comment: This is a big file. I take help to add textblock from it https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86760/add-a-border-to-textblock

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[showboxes]{textpos}

\begin{document}

\tekstblokroolkulur{blue}%
\tekstblokkulur{white}%
\begin{textblock}{3.84}(1.40,1.28)    % tweak here: {box width}(leftposition, rightposition)
     \noindent
     \footnotesize%
     978-1-7281-5242-4/19 2019 IEEE
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

(off-topic: you are missing `%` at most of your line endings, which will insert additional spaces)